# How to add an observation category on scanpy based on another observation?

Tags: python, metadata, rna-seq, scanpy

I have a concatenated single-cell RNAseq anndata with

```
obs: 'Age', 'EPNsubtype', 'Region', 'Subclass', 
'Taxonomy_group', 'Tissue', 'batch', 'pheno', 'sample', 
'subtype', 'treatment', 'n_genes', 'percent_mito', 
'n_counts', 'leiden'
```

And I want to create another obs `'Sex'` for the different 'samples'

I know I can create a new obs with

```
adata.obs["sex"] = "female"
```

but how would I do it for particular sample categories and not the entire set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So the `adata.obs` (or the `adata.var`) attribute of the AnnData is a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). So you can use them as such.

For example, imagine that the `adata.obs` contains the information on the cells labeled `AACT`, `AACG` and `AACC`. Also imagine that the dataframe contains the information of the Age and the Tissue. The dataframe will contain 3 indexes which correspond to the labels of the cells and two columns which corresponds to `Age` and `Tissue`.

```
adata.obs
  Index   Age  Tissue
  AACT    26   Lung
  AACG    40   Lung
  AACC    34   Lung
```

Now, like you said, if you type `adata.obs['sex'] = 'female'`, it will create a new column called `sex` with the string "female" for every index of the dataframe.

```
adata.obs
  Index   Age  Tissue  sex
  AACT    26   Lung    female
  AACG    40   Lung    female
  AACC    34   Lung    female
```

Imagine that the cell `AACC` and `AACG` actually comes from a "male" patient, you could write:

```
male_patients = ['AACC', 'AACG']
adata.obs.loc[male_patients, 'sex'] = 'male'
```

which would result in :

```
adata.obs
  Index   Age  Tissue  sex
  AACT    26   Lung    female
  AACG    40   Lung    male
  AACC    34   Lung    male
```

Note that I have used the [`.loc\[\]`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-loc/) attribute to access to specific element of the dataframe by using the index name (`['AACC', 'AACG']`) and the columns names (`'sex'`).

I suggest you follow some tutorial to learn how to work with python pandas DataFrame (example: ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html))).